# Adding several elements to a listbox menu in vba

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am trying to create a menu with list boxes in order to be able to select a number of customers from a list in an excel sheet. There are two list boxes, one with all the (default) data and one with the selected customers.
There is no problem adding one customer but when I add a second customer the graphic interface shows nothing, but after some debugging, the SelectedCustomers.RowSource still have the two rows in its data:

```
?SelectedCustomers.RowSource
$8:$8,$11:$11
```

This would have me believe there is some error with how I save the data or some limitations to Excel that I am not aware of. This is the code I use to save the data:

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
Dim temp As Range

For i = 0 To DefCustomers.ListCount - 1
    If DefCustomers.Selected(i) = True Then
        If temp Is Nothing Then
            Set temp = Range(Rows(i + 4).Address)
        Else
            Set temp = Application.Union(temp, Range(Rows(i + 4).Address))
        End If
    End If
Next i

SelectedCustomers.RowSource = temp.Address
End Sub
```

Has someone experienced this before or know what the problem might be?

Comment: I realised that listbox.rowsource does not support unpontinuous rows, which caused my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **RowSource** use [AddItem method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835328%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
For i = 0 To DefCustomers.ListCount - 1
    If DefCustomers.Selected(i) Then
        SelectedCustomers.AddItem DefCustomers.Selected(i)
    End If
Next i
```

There are known issues with **ListBox.RowSource** property in Excel VBA.

**[EDIT]**

After the discussion...

No matter of number of columns, you can copy rows from source sheet into another sheet, then bind *SelectedCustomers* listbox to that data

Comment: Yes, I tried that previously, but I have 209 columns for each item and the additem method only adds one column per use of the method, so I would have to use it 209 times? Or is it possible to add all columns in one "additem method usage"?

Comment: Yes, it is a way. Why 209 columns?

Comment: Well let's see if I can explain: the data in the sheet is organised such that the rows represent the customers, then the columns represent different aspects of products, for example which year the price was decided for a customer, which percentages a certain customers get of a certain product. There are maybe 10 aspects for each products or so, therefore I need the operator to be able to choose which customers and which products it wants to look at. Therefore I thought it would be easier to simply choose all of the product aspects and then filter them out later in the process.

Comment: No matter of number of columns, you can copy rows from source sheet into another sheet, then bind SelectedCustomers listbox to that data.

Comment: Filip, let me know if it helped ;)

Comment: Yeah, so update: What i did was that I loaded data to a new sheet and created a new named ranged, then assigned the listbox.rowsource to that named range and it worked great, it's a bit slow but works. The original problem was that rowsource apparently cannot contain unpontinuous ranges.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @FilipSchöllin, can i post it as an answer? Could you accept it then?

Comment: Done ;) See the content after **EDIT** part ;)